# What is the runtime complexity of this short code?

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I found this solution on a programming practice site and it said that the complexity is O(N). However, it looks more like O(N^2) to me. Can someone please tell me why this is O(N) ?

```
public static void transposeMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    int n = matrix.length - 1;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j <= n; j++){
            temp = matrix[i][j];
            matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re right. That source is wrong.

Comment: You may be using a different definition of N.

Comment: What is the source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is `N`?

If `N` is `max(matrix.length, matrix[0].length)`, then the algorithm is O(N^2), as you say.

If `N` is *the total size of the matrix*, then the algorithm is O(N).

It's always very important to define exactly what `N` is in big-O notation. When learning Big-O, most discussions revolve around single-dimensional inputs, and people assume you don't have to define `N`. In the real world, things are dirty, we deal with multidimensional inputs, and you have to be very clear about what `N` is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not O(n). It's O(n^2). Specifically, it will execute n-i swaps for 0 ≤ i ≤ n. Thus it will execute 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n swaps = n(n+1)/2 swaps, which is O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

> n = matrix.length - 1;

**Time Complexity** : O(N^2)

**Space Complexity**: O(1)

> Explanation:  In first for loop i will go from (0 --- N). And in
>   second for loop, j will go from (i+1 --- N).  For i = 0, you iterate
>   N-1 elements. For i = 1, you iterate N-2 elements. Similarly, For i =
>   N-1, you iterate for last element

```
In total, T  = (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ... + 2 + 1

T ~ N * (1+2+3+...+N)

T ~ O(N^2)
```